# apt-get with fix broken flag not working for me

Tags: package-management, source-packages

You have broken packages installed, fix them before upgrading. I tried to fix the issue with "sudo apt-get -f install" but above error blooms]

[image]

Comment: The problem seems clearly stated in the error mesage: `no space left on device`, as is the most likely solution: `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Yes, you are having disk space issues. Look at `du -sh` and then clear out some hard drive space.

Comment: Please [Don't upload images, use code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: root@server:~# du -sh
119G .

Comment: root@server:~# du -sh
119G .
root@server:~# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        786M   86M  700M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/server--vg-root  911G  139G  726G  17% /

Comment: 726G space are free

Comment: Hi user535733 I tried to auto remove but gives me error back as  E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f

Comment: #BoomShado Thanks buddy I was need more explanation as I'm new bye anyway Thanks a Lot :)